# NSDictionary Getting Repeated values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I know this may be a repeated question but I googled a lot but not able to find a suitable answer for me.

I have a `NSMutableArray` which has `two` `NSDictionary` with Keys and values which I need to populated on a `UITableView`. I have retrieved the value of the `dictionary` which I'm going populate using

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [responseArray valueForKey:@"Table"];
```

And I did like

```
NSMutableSet *names = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray *mutArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id obj in mutArray) {

    NSString *destinationName = [obj valueForKey:@"AssetClassName"];

    if (![names containsObject:destinationName]) {

       [mutArray1 addObject:destinationName];
       [names addObject:destinationName];

    }
}
```

Because the value `AssetClassName` is repeated. Now I have three values in `mutArray1` which I need to show as `UITableView` section. Under `AssetClassName` I have Some data which determines the row in that section.

For retrieving that data I'm doing like

```
for (int i = 0; i < [mutArray1 count]; i++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *a = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *b = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in mutArray) {

        if ([[mutArray1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:@"AssetClassName"]]) {

           [a setObject:[dict objectForKey: @"SubAssetClassName"] forKey:@"Investment Categories"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Amount"] forKey:@"Amount (EUR)"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"AllocationPercentage"] forKey:@"%"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"ModelAllocationPercentage"] forKey:@"ModelAllocationPercentage"];

           [b setObject:a forKey:[dict valueForKey:@"SubAssetClassName"]];

           [mutdict setObject:b forKey:[dict valueForKey:@"AssetClassName"]];
        }
    }
}
```

`mutdict` is a `NSMutableDictionary` declared globally and is instantiate in `viewdidLoad`

```
mutdict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

The values are inserted into `mutdict` as I needed. Each `SubAssetClassName` is added into `AssetclassName` accordingly.

But my problem is in my final dictionary i.e `mutdict` the values for `SubAssetClassName` is repeated.

Can anybody tell how to solve this.

**My console**

```
"AssetClassName" =     {

    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "HIGH YIELD BONDS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 22;
    };
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "HIGH YIELD BONDS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 22;
    };
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "HIGH YIELD BONDS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 22;
    };
};
"AssetClassName" =     {
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "EMERGING MARKETS EQUITIES";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 10;
    };
};
"AssetClassName" =     {
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "STRUCTURED PRODUCTS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 10;
    };
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "STRUCTURED PRODUCTS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 10;
    };
    "SubAssetClass" =         {
        "%" = 0;
        "Amount (EUR)" = 0;
        "Investment Categories" = "STRUCTURED PRODUCTS";
        "ModelAllocationPercentage" = 10;
    };
};
}
```

Here I can see that all `SubAssetClass` values are same for each section but actually its not.

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of your mutable dictionary inside the loop. Right now you create one instance and update it over and over. This results in one dictionary being added over and over.

Change you code as follows:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [mutArray1 count]; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *b = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in mutArray) {
        if ([[mutArray1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:@"AssetClassName"]]) {
           NSMutableDictionary *a = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

           [a setObject:[dict objectForKey: @"SubAssetClassName"] forKey:@"Investment Categories"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Amount"] forKey:@"Amount (EUR)"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"AllocationPercentage"] forKey:@"%"];
           [a setObject:[dict valueForKey:@"ModelAllocationPercentage"] forKey:@"ModelAllocationPercentage"];

           [b setObject:a forKey:[dict valueForKey:@"SubAssetClassName"]];

           [mutdict setObject:b forKey:[dict valueForKey:@"AssetClassName"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in most cases you should not be using `valueForKey:`. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a clear and specific need to use key-value coding instead of simply getting an object from the dictionary for a given key.

Comment: Thank u.... one more question in my UITableView cell i'm getting these values like `NSDictionary *rowData = [mutdict valueForKeyPath:[sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];` but don't know how to populate each cell with SubAssetClass name and value. can u help with that.

Comment: If you have another question, please post a new question. Be sure to include all relevant details in the question.

Comment: Ok as you said i asked another question you can check that in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680845/populate-nsmutabledictionary-value-to-uitableviewcell)